# how to mock nest interface on NSubstitute

Tags: nsubstitute

I have a nested interface defined as:

```cs
public IMyInterface {
    void DoSomething()
}

public class MyClassA: IMyInterface {}

public class MyClassB: IMyInterface {}

public class MyWrapperClass: IMyInterface
{
    private IMyInterface _myClass;

    public MyWrapperClass()
    {
        _myClass = new MyClassA();
    }

    public MyWrapperClass UseClassB()
    {
        _myClass = new MyClassB();
        return this;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _myClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

In my code, I have something like this:

```cs
public void run(IMyInterface myWrapper){
    
    wrapper.UseClassB().DoSomething();
}
```

in the mock, want to check if the `DoSomething()` is called `1` once. I'm doing so like;

```cs
var mockedWrapper = Substitute.For<MyWrapperClass>();

mockedWrapper.UseClassB().DoSomething();

run(mockedWrapper)

mockedWrapper.Received().UseClassB().DoSomething();
```

the `Received()` will pass on `Received(2)` instead of `Received(1)`, it seems the NSubstitute counter the `.UseClassB()` when sent up the mock method...

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a substitute for `MyWrapperClass`, but you typically create a substitute of an interface. Straight from the NSubstitute docs:

https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/

> The basic syntax for creating a substitute is:
>
> ```
> var substitute = Substitute.For<ISomeInterface>();
> ```
>
> This is how you’ll normally create substitutes for types. Generally this type will be an interface, but you can also substitute classes in cases of emergency.

The section beneath that details how classes can be substituted, but there are a number of caveats. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, you may be best reading that document to see how it relates to what you're trying to do, or post a follow up question.